# How to return the name of the element using which.min function in R

Tags: r

I would like to return the minimum values out of a list. I tried to use `which.min`, however, it returns to me the value only. I tried `myresult[which.min(myresult)` and it does not return what I expect. I would like to return the name of the model that has the minimum values + the minimum value itself.

Here is my code:

```
  AICShs <– list(-6.25986260054445, -6.25212590009515, -6.24824253719408, 
-6.25582853027039, -6.26461885025024, -6.26629173617934, 
-6.25081089183173, -6.26983146789366, -6.26359136419188)


AICShN <–list(-6.11567547068201, -6.12585791111017, -6.1304996101667, 
-6.11768152793088, -6.14212680478656, -6.12280629573664, 
-6.12768871580412, -6.15292645403079, -6.1428785715995)

names1 <- c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

lapply(setNames(unlist(AICShN), paste0(names1, '_Model')), function(x) 
  setNames(x, paste0('Res_', seq_along(x))))
AICShN[which.min(AICShN)]
```

Each list returns `9` results, I would like to give them a name and return the names.

```
$`2_Model`
    Res_1 
-6.125858
```

Comment: Right now, your `lapply` is not storing anything anywhere. If you do `AICShN <- lapply(*your code*)` then you will get the result that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As slamballais already mentioned, your `lapply` only prints out the values without storing them. This:

```
AICShs <- list(-6.25986260054445, -6.25212590009515, -6.24824253719408, 
               -6.25582853027039, -6.26461885025024, -6.26629173617934, 
               -6.25081089183173, -6.26983146789366, -6.26359136419188)

AICShN <- list(-6.11567547068201, -6.12585791111017, -6.1304996101667, 
              -6.11768152793088, -6.14212680478656, -6.12280629573664, 
              -6.12768871580412, -6.15292645403079, -6.1428785715995)

names1 <- c("1","2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

result <- lapply(setNames(unlist(AICShN), paste0(names1, '_Model')), function(x) 
  setNames(x, paste0('Res_', seq_along(x))))
which.min(result)
```

will give the result

```
> which.min(result)
8_Model 
      8
```

You'll get the value easily by running `AICShN[[which.min(AICShN)]]` while `which.min(AICShN)` gives you the index of the item with the minimum value. I suppose your real values are not generated like this example data? (Otherwise, since your `names1` vector and the index of each value are identical, you could simply use paste the `which.min(AICShN)` output and `"_Model"`.) Hope this answers your question.